TypeError: Unhashable Type: 'list' in pytest, selenium
`Hi, I am running the following code and getting the error as Typeerror: Unhashable type: list
Could anyone help on what am i doing wrong here?
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pytest
import time
#from test_data import  credentials




def credentials():
    return [
        ("admin","qwerl123"),
            ]



@pytest.mark.usefixtures("username", "password",credentials())
def test_login(username,password, get_browser):
    driver = get_browser
    driver.get("https://xxxxxxxxxx")
    log_in_homepage = driver.find_element(By.ID, "login").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']").send_keys(username);
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']").send_keys(password);
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)`your text`
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='signin']").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    time.sleep(1)

I tried running the code and got error as
Typeerror: unhashable type: list`
